# Not able to launch Robotium tests from my android activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, robotium, android-instrumentation

I have two projects

One is Android test project with all android robotium tests which I run from eclipse. I am able to run it successfully using eclipse and `adb shell` am on command line.

I am trying to launch the test project using android app(activity), I always get below error when trying to do so

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception thrown in onCreate() of
>   ComponentInfo{com.test.example/pl.polidea.instrumentation.PolideaInstrumentationTestRunner}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.util.Set android.os.Bundle.keySet()' on a null object reference

Does anyone know, what am I doing wrong here?